# Drupal 8 disable theme.yml cache

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-8

When I change some info in theme.yml the chagnes are not activated on the site. The changes only are activated when I clean the cache on `admin/config/development/performance`. I have done all things from [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914) and also tried using "Rebuild the theme registry on every page load" with Devel module. It did not help me. Is there any way to completely disable cache?

Did the drupal developers assume the theme developer should click the button every time he changes some theme option?

Comment: Use this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914), you will find here eveything what you need. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @D.Erashkin did you read my answer? I included your link in it and told that  that operations did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Open development.services.yml in the sites folder and add the following block to disable the twig cache:

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
```

NOTE: If the parameters block is already present in the yml file, append the twig.config block to it.

Afterwards you have to rebuild the Drupal cache otherwise your website will encounter an unexpected error on page reload. This can be done by with drush:

```
drush cr
```

from: https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

If you have drupal console installed, just put:

```
drupal site:mode dev
```

Comment: You wrote steps from the link from the question. Logic?